# I want to modify fab of flutter in such a way that it looks like the following image upon tap

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, floating-action-button, dart-pub

[image: Want fab button to look like this upon tap]

I want to modify fab of flutter in such a way that it looks like this image upon tap.Where the 3 tiles can basically contain anything.
The closest i could find was this
:- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_boom_menu
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: BoomMenu(
      animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
      animatedIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 22.0),
      //child: Icon(Icons.add),
      onOpen: () => print('OPENING DIAL'),
      onClose: () => print('DIAL CLOSED'),
      scrollVisible: scrollVisible,
      overlayColor: Colors.black,
      overlayOpacity: 0.7,
      children: [
        MenuItem(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: new BoxConstraints(
    minHeight: 5.0,
    minWidth: 5.0,
    maxHeight: 30.0,
    maxWidth: 30.0,
  ),
  child: new DecoratedBox(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
  ),
),
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
          onTap: () => print('FIRST CHILD'),
        ),


      ],
    ),
    );
}
```